# How can I composite the new shadow catcher that should work with reflections in latest versions of blender?

Tags: shadowcatcher

There are no so many shadow catcher youtube tutorials on blender, and all of them are outdated. I tried using the new shadow catcher that should work with reflections also and couldn't make it look good. I am not good at compositing. So if anyone understand the new shadow catcher that comes with latest versions of blender, please explain how to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Enable *Environment* and *Shadow Catcher* in the *Light* subpanel of the *Passes* panel of the *View Layers* Properties tab in the Properties Editor.

  (Properties Editor → View Layers → Passes → Light)
- Select the object you want to be a shadow catcher and enable *Shadow* in the *Ray Visibility* subpanel of the *Visibility* panel of the *Object* Properties tab in the Properties Editor.

  (Properties Editor → Object → Visibility → Ray Visibility)
- Set up the compositor nodes that I've highlighted in this screenshot:
  [image: Compositor nodes to enable shadow catcher]

Note that I am using a compositor denoiser in this screen shot.  If you don't want to do that, then connect the *Image* output of the Render Layers node to the lower input of the *Alpha Over* node.

Also note that this setup is for *Cycles*.

The key thing here is that if you want color and reflections you need to multiply the *Shadow Catcher* and *Env* pass outputs of the Render Layer and then you need to use that as the *Alpha Over* input to composite the shadow catcher with the image.

You can add more compositing nodes after the *Alpha Over* or between the (Denoise) *Image* and the *Alpha Over*, of course.

You may find [this tutorial](https://www.blendernation.com/2021/12/05/new-shadow-catcher-features-in-blender-3-0-cycles-x-tutorial/) useful for more detail.

Comment: Thanks. Something is not working though. When I hit render, my shadow catcher object is all pure black.
I am using 3.2

Comment: Could be a bug in 3.2 alpha or something changed. I don’t use the betas but maybe someone else will know.

Comment: I think I fixed it by disabling transparent in the film tab of the render properties panel !

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/1v4bxFM.png